# Best practice for a triangular web design?

Tags: html, css

I was seeking the best method to create triangular web page design such as below:

[image: Template layout of triangles]

In such case text inside triangles has to be wrapped, triangles will indent text, and those triangles can have backgrounds..

Using CSS (border trick) to make triangle does seem to work, but fails when trying to set a background to it.

Using images (e.g. svg) as background to div, and specifying widths of paragraphs inside to seem triangular ([example](http://www.csstextwrap.com/)), has b bad impacts on browser compatibility and really bad when it comes to responsiveness.

Using some css3 and creating skewed divs seems to be a good option ([example](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/liDCz)), but it might be a bit heavy option and isn't supported in all browser (all new browsers still)

```
transform-origin: 100% 0;
transform: skewX(-55.98deg);
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this web design. This is magazine design. This will be really hard (if not impossible) to achieve on web and work on all browsers.

Comment: That is understandable, still Web design is incorporating new concepts daily. It is still achievable, but looking for best practice with best compatibility.

Comment: I agree, but at this point I don't know if you can do that design and keep the website all-browsers compatible.

Comment: You might want to consider how user-friendly this design is. Sure, it looks funky, but is it easy for users to read the text, especially the text in the triangle on the left? The further the text layout of a design deviates from the norm, the more difficult it is for users to understand the contents--they will read it more slowly and be more likely to leave the page without reading.

Comment: You need to use [CSS Regions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-regions/) and [CSS Exclusions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-exclusions/), but its not supported in all browsers yet. see http://webplatform.adobe.com/regions/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/regions/adobe/

Comment: Asking for "best practices" seems off-topic... under the _"primarily opinion based"_ reason.

Comment: Aside from lacking support, CSS regions have also been a [matter of controversy](http://alistapart.com/blog/post/css-regions-considered-harmful). Google [dropped them](http://slashdot.org/story/14/01/29/1745233/google-planning-to-remove-css-regions-from-blink) and Mozilla never planned to implement them. Although [opinions about this vary](http://css-tricks.com/css-regions-matter/), I would be very cautious before planning a design that depends on CSS regions.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like this: http://webplatform.adobe.com/shapes/ . But it is still experimental i believe and you wont find support for IE10 and below.